# TypeError: NewPersonAboutText() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qtextedit

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить ошибку:

> TypeError: NewPersonAboutText() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

```
...

class NewPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
# События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.preview.clicked.connect(self.Preview)
# Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)


# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ИМЯ"
    def NewPersonName(self, name):
        self.name = name

# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ"
    def NewPersonAboutText(self, text):
        self.text = text

...
```

---

Интерфейс:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_newperson(object):
    def setupUi(self, newperson):
        newperson.setObjectName("newperson")
        newperson.resize(600, 600)
        newperson.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        newperson.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 62, 301, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(newperson)
        self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 231, 20))
        self.name.setObjectName("name")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 241, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.aboutpersontext = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(newperson)
        self.aboutpersontext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 171, 501, 241))
        self.aboutpersontext.setObjectName("aboutpersontext")
        self.image = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 502, 131, 51))
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.makeperson = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.makeperson.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 502, 131, 51))
        self.makeperson.setObjectName("makeperson")
        self.preview = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.preview.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 502, 171, 51))
        self.preview.setObjectName("preview")

        self.retranslateUi(newperson)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(newperson)

    def retranslateUi(self, newperson):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        newperson.setWindowTitle(_translate("newperson", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("newperson", "Имя исторической личности:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("newperson", "Создание новой исторической личности"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("newperson", "Введите его описание:"))
        self.image.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить картинку"))
        self.makeperson.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить персонажа"))
        self.preview.setText(_translate("newperson", "Предварительный просмотр"))
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста свой файл, который содержит класс Ui_newperson

Comment: @S.Nick Изменил вопрос

Comment: `QTextEdit::textChanged()`  Этот сигнал испускается при изменении содержимого документа; например, при вставке или удалении текста или при форматировании. Примечание. Сигнал уведомления для свойства `html`. Смотрите http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textChanged

Comment: @S.Nick Спасибо. Тут поможете? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898790/qtwidgets-qfiledialog-getopenfilename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QTextEdit::**textChanged()**
>
> Сигнал **textChanged()** испускается всякий раз,
> когда текст изменяется (в результате setText() или через сам редактор).

Т.е. данный сигнал сработает когда текст изменяется и вызовет на исполнение
слот `self.NewPersonAboutText()`, при этом никакие аргументы в слот не передаются.

```
...
    self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)

def NewPersonAboutText(self):                       # - , text - надо убрать):
    ...
```

Пробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from newperson_ui import Ui_newperson

class NewPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
# События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.preview.clicked.connect(self.Preview)
# Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.textChanged[str].connect(self.NewPersonName)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)


# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ИМЯ"
    def NewPersonName(self, name):
        print("def NewPersonName(self, name):", name)
        self.name = name

# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ"
    def NewPersonAboutText(self):                       # - , text):
        #self.text = text
        self.text = self.ui.aboutpersontext.toPlainText()
        print("def NewPersonAboutText(self):", self.text)

# +++
    def ChoiceImage(self):
        print("def ChoiceImage(self, text):",self.sender())
# +++
    def MakeNewPerson(self):
        print("def MakeNewPerson(self, text):",self.sender())    
# +++
    def Preview(self):
        print("def Preview(self, text):",self.sender())         
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = NewPerson()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]