# QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

```
def ChoiceImage(self):
    self.FaceOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите картинку с лицом исторической личности", "/")
```

Если файл выбран, как мне его пересохранить в другое место?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPixmap, QFileDialog, QApplication


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button_open = QPushButton('Выбрать картинку')
        self.button_open.clicked.connect(self._on_open_image)

        self.button_save_as = QPushButton('Сохранить картинку')
        self.button_save_as.clicked.connect(self._on_save_as_image)

        self.label_image = QLabel()

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_open)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_save_as)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label_image)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_open_image(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выбор картинки", None, "Image (*.png *.jpg)")[0]
        if not file_name:
            return

        pixmap = QPixmap(file_name)
        self.label_image.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def _on_save_as_image(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Сохранение картинки", 'img.jpg', "Image (*.png *.jpg)")[0]
        if not file_name:
            return

        self.label_image.pixmap().save(file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** Реализация без `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName`. Путь сохранения указывается в переменной:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button_open = QPushButton('Выбрать картинку')
        self.button_open.clicked.connect(self._on_open_image)

        self.button_save_as = QPushButton('Сохранить картинку')
        self.button_save_as.clicked.connect(self._on_save_as_image)

        self.label_image = QLabel()

        # Путь сохранения файла
        self.save_file_name = 'C:/img.jpg'

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_open)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_save_as)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label_image)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_open_image(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выбор картинки", None, "Image (*.png *.jpg)")[0]
        if not file_name:
            return

        pixmap = QPixmap(file_name)
        self.label_image.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def _on_save_as_image(self):
        self.label_image.pixmap().save(self.save_file_name)
```

Comment: Прошу прощения не уточнил, Файл я должен сохранить не через QFileDialog

Comment: @МаксимХалин, уточняйте тогда до конца ) QFileDialog не сохраняет файл, он выбирает место где его сохранить, полный путь. А сохранением файла занимается метод `save` у `pixmap`

Comment: Хм. Понял, спасибо. Интересно, как же тогда реализовать

Comment: @МаксимХалин, обновил ответ, вам это нужно было? :) Если что, вы можете сразу в `_on_open_image` делать сохрание файла (или его копирование) в нужную вам папку. Показать как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте:

```
import sys
from os import getcwd

from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QPushButton, QFileDialog

class QLabelClickable(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QLabelClickable, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class mostrarImagen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mostrarImagen, self).__init__(parent) 

        self.setWindowTitle("Выбор каотинки")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("logo.png"))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.labelImage = QLabelClickable(self)
        self.labelImage.setGeometry(15, 15, 118, 130)
        self.labelImage.setToolTip("Картинка")
        self.labelImage.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        self.labelImage.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel {background-color: write; border: 1px solid "
            "#0DFFD7; border-radius: 5px;}")
        self.labelImage.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # ... по нажатии кнопки выходило окно, в котором пользователь указывает где находиться картинка.
        buttonSelect = QPushButton("Выбрать картинку", self)
        buttonSelect.setToolTip("buttonSelect")
        buttonSelect.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        buttonSelect.setGeometry(143, 15, 120, 25)

        buttonRemove = QPushButton("Удалить картинку", self)
        buttonRemove.setToolTip("buttonRemove")
        buttonRemove.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        buttonRemove.setGeometry(143, 45, 120, 25)        

        self.labelImage.clicked.connect(self.seleccionarImagen)
        buttonSelect.clicked.connect(self.seleccionarImagen)
        buttonRemove.clicked.connect(lambda: self.labelImage.clear())


    def seleccionarImagen(self):
        imagen, extension = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(      # ... похожа на 'Open'
            self, "Выбор каотинки", getcwd(),
            "Image (*.png *.jpg)",
            options=QFileDialog.Options())

        if imagen:
            # Функции QPixmap.scaled() возвращают масштабированные копии pixmap
            pixmapImagen = QPixmap(imagen).scaled(112, 128,
                               Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                               Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.labelImage.setPixmap(pixmapImagen)           # После эта картинка вставляется в QLablе.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mostrarImagen()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, я выбрал файл, мне нужно его сохранить. Как мне это сделать? Вернее сохранить, в другое место

Comment: То есть я выбираю файл в переменную. А после сохраняю его

Comment: @Максим Халин  сохранить на диск?

Comment: Да, сохранить в папку, которую я укажу сам